# parse json with regex and deserialize to collection

Tags: c#, regex, string, json, serialization

Hi I need parse and deserialize pseudo JSON string.

**Input data:**

```
{aBubbleData[
    'jaja2581'
]={
    "idUser": 4203666,
    "nick": "JAja2581",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 9,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "jaja2581",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 20,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "2012-01-28"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "88",
        "cityName": "Partiz\u00e1nske"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "3",
        "roomName": "Iba RP",
        "lastLogin": 1333308615
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 9,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "Som narcis a co Aj jedno slovo potop\u00ed sny...Aj jeden de\u0148\r\nzmen\u00ed \u017eivot...Aj jeden poh\u013ead dok\u00e1\u017ee\r\nu\u010darova\u0165...Aj jedno objatie dok\u00e1\u017ee naplni\u0165\r\npr\u00e1zdnu du\u0161u...",
        "addTime": "1332089086"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    'majinka155'
]={
    "idUser": 4433815,
    "nick": "Majinka155",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 7,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "majinka155",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 22,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "0000-00-00"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "137",
        "cityName": "Nem\u0161ov\u00e1"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "9",
        "roomName": "Do pohody",
        "lastLogin": 1333306831
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 7,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "\u017eivot ti rany d\u00e1va, ale ty nie si sama, m\u00e1\u0161 skvel\u00fa l\u00e1sku a nie len na obr\u00e1zku, m\u00e1\u0161 milovan\u00fa os\u00f4bku, \u010do pri tebe stoj\u00ed, preto sa v\u0161etko na svete zahoj\u00ed...",
        "addTime": "1332102387"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
}
    "idUser": 4460957,
    "nick": "jankaxxx6",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 21,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "jankaxxx6",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 20,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4460957PARAM_ext?v=1",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4460957PARAM_ext?v=1",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4460957PARAM_ext?v=1"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "2012-03-20"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "139",
        "cityName": "Tren\u010d\u00edn"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "3",
        "roomName": "Iba RP",
        "lastLogin": 1333308360
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 21,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 1,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": ".....",
        "addTime": "1329989508"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    'doda1309'
]={
    "idUser": 4656395,
    "nick": "doda1309",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 8,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "doda1309",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 19,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4656395PARAM_ext?v=4",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4656395PARAM_ext?v=4",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4656395PARAM_ext?v=4"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "0000-00-00"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "97",
        "cityName": "Pova\u017esk\u00e1 Bystrica"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "18",
        "roomName": "\u017dilina",
        "lastLogin": 1333307236
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 8,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "Pr\u00edbeh jedn\u00e9ho \u010dloveka, je aj pr\u00edbehom t\u00fdch, \u010do svoje \u017eivoty spolu sn\u00edm spojili:):-*",
        "addTime": "1265308486"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    'jamelka12'
]={
    "idUser": 4973811,
    "nick": "jamelka12",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 8,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "jamelka12",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 23,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4973811PARAM_ext?v=3",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4973811PARAM_ext?v=3",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4973811PARAM_ext?v=3"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "2012-02-25"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "35",
        "cityName": "Dubnica nad V\u00e1hom"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "26",
        "roomName": "Tren\u010d\u00edn",
        "lastLogin": 1333301142
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 8,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "Niektor\u00ed \u013eudia nerobia chyby, preto\u017ee sa v\u00f4bec nepok\u00fasili urobi\u0165 nie\u010do \u010do stoj\u00ed za to ....",
        "addTime": "1333188968"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    'mary1102'
]={
    "idUser": 5881639,
    "nick": "Mary1102",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 4,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "mary1102",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 18,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_5881639PARAM_ext?v=3",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_5881639PARAM_ext?v=3",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_5881639PARAM_ext?v=3"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "2010-02-26"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "97",
        "cityName": "Pova\u017esk\u00e1 Bystrica"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "37",
        "roomName": "Zahrani\u010die",
        "lastLogin": 1333305516
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 4,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "",
        "addTime": "1332587902"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    'rytmusbaba46'
]={
    "idUser": 8066425,
    "nick": "rytmusbaba46",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 16,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "rytmusbaba46",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 23,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_8066425PARAM_ext?v=7",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_8066425PARAM_ext?v=7",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_8066425PARAM_ext?v=7"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "2011-01-17"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "139",
        "cityName": "Tren\u010d\u00edn"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "9",
        "roomName": "Do pohody",
        "lastLogin": 1333299734
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 16,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 3,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 90,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "\u201eNaozajstn\u00e9ho priate\u013ea nezauj\u00edma, \u010di m\u00e1\u0161 peniaze, \u010di m\u00e1\u0161 n\u00e1ladu, ko\u013eko v\u00e1\u017ei\u0161, \u017ee m\u00e1\u0161 rozbit\u00fd dom, ak\u00e9 m\u00e1\u0161 auto, ak\u00fa m\u00e1\u0161 minulos\u0165, alebo \u017ee \u010di tvoja rodina je pl",
        "addTime": "1331573798"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    '10_lucinka_1'
]={
    "idUser": 11466424,
    "nick": "10_LUCINKA_1",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 16,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "10_lucinka_1",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 14,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_11466424PARAM_ext?v=3",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_11466424PARAM_ext?v=3",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_11466424PARAM_ext?v=3"
    },
    "PLUS": {
        "active": false,
        "activeTo": "2012-03-23"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "2",
        "cityName": "B\u00e1novce nad Bebravou"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "3",
        "roomName": "Iba RP",
        "lastLogin": 1333304089
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 16,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 2,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": ":) :*",
        "addTime": "1331928446"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "noAddGift": 1
};aBubbleData[
    'digica'
]={
    "idUser": 11970671,
    "nick": "digica",
    "photo": 1,
    "sex": 2,
    "photoAlbums": 27,
    "videoAlbums": 0,
    "sefNick": "digica",
    "profilPercent": 100,
    "emphasis": false,
    "age": 29,
    "isBlocked": false,
    "PHOTO": {
        "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_11970671PARAM_ext?v=2",
        "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_11970671PARAM_ext?v=2",
        "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_11970671PARAM_ext?v=2"
    },
    "LOCATION": {
        "idRegion": "6",
        "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
        "idCity": "103",
        "cityName": "Prievidza"
    },
    "STATUS": {
        "isLoged": true,
        "isChating": true,
        "idChat": "3",
        "roomName": "Iba RP",
        "lastLogin": 1333304814
    },
    "PROJECT_STATUS": {
        "photoAlbums": 27,
        "photoAlbumsFavs": 1,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
        "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
        "blogPosts": 0
    },
    "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
        "statusMessage": "ZO VSETKYCH BREMIEN NA SVETE JE NAJTAZSIA BYTOST,KTORU SME PRESTALI MILOVAT.",
        "addTime": "1333294363"
    },
    "isFriend": false,
    "isIamFriend": false,
    "bubbleSkinNumber": 18,
    "noAddGift": 1
};
```

Problem is that string above is not valid JSON. String contains  list of user nicks and profiles.

My idea is transfor string above to this format:

```
{
    "userNick": {
        "idUser": 4203666,
        "nick": "JAja2581",
        "photo": 1,
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 9,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "sefNick": "jaja2581",
        "profilPercent": 100,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 20,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk/profil/n_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
            "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk/profil/m_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
            "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk/profil/s_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "2012-01-28"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "6",
            "regionName": "Trenčianskykraj",
            "idCity": "88",
            "cityName": "Partizánske"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": true,
            "isChating": true,
            "idChat": "3",
            "roomName": "IbaRP",
            "lastLogin": 1333308615
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 9,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbums": 0,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": "SomnarcisacoAjjednoslovopotopísny...Ajjedendeň\r\nzmeníživot...Ajjedenpohľaddokáže\r\nučarovať...Ajjednoobjatiedokáženaplniť\r\nprázdnudušu...",
            "addTime": "1332089086"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false,
        "noAddGift": 1
    }
}
```

If I have json string in this format it will be possible deserialize do Dictionary.

So my problem is how parse nicks and profiles from string on the top.

One user is represents with string in this format:

```
aBubbleData[
        'jaja2581'
    ]={
        "idUser": 4203666,
        "nick": "JAja2581",
        "photo": 1,
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 9,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "sefNick": "jaja2581",
        "profilPercent": 100,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 20,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
            "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
            "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "2012-01-28"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "6",
            "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
            "idCity": "88",
            "cityName": "Partiz\u00e1nske"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": true,
            "isChating": true,
            "idChat": "3",
            "roomName": "Iba RP",
            "lastLogin": 1333308615
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 9,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbums": 0,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": "Som narcis a co Aj jedno slovo potop\u00ed sny...Aj jeden de\u0148\r\nzmen\u00ed \u017eivot...Aj jeden poh\u013ead dok\u00e1\u017ee\r\nu\u010darova\u0165...Aj jedno objatie dok\u00e1\u017ee naplni\u0165\r\npr\u00e1zdnu du\u0161u...",
            "addTime": "1332089086"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false,
        "noAddGift": 1
    };aBubbleData[
        'majinka155'
    ]={
        "idUser": 4433815,
        "nick": "Majinka155",
        "photo": 1,
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 7,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "sefNick": "majinka155",
        "profilPercent": 100,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 22,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1",
            "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1",
            "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "0000-00-00"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "6",
            "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
            "idCity": "137",
            "cityName": "Nem\u0161ov\u00e1"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": true,
            "isChating": true,
            "idChat": "9",
            "roomName": "Do pohody",
            "lastLogin": 1333306831
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 7,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbums": 0,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": "\u017eivot ti rany d\u00e1va, ale ty nie si sama, m\u00e1\u0161 skvel\u00fa l\u00e1sku a nie len na obr\u00e1zku, m\u00e1\u0161 milovan\u00fa os\u00f4bku, \u010do pri tebe stoj\u00ed, preto sa v\u0161etko na svete zahoj\u00ed...",
            "addTime": "1332102387"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false,
        "noAddGift": 1
    }
```

**NICK** I can parse from this part:

```
aBubbleData[
        'jaja2581'
    ]
```

In this case nick is **jaja2581**

**USER PROFILE** is in this case this part:

```
{
        "idUser": 4203666,
        "nick": "JAja2581",
        "photo": 1,
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 9,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "sefNick": "jaja2581",
        "profilPercent": 100,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 20,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
            "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4",
            "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4203666PARAM_ext?v=4"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "2012-01-28"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "6",
            "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
            "idCity": "88",
            "cityName": "Partiz\u00e1nske"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": true,
            "isChating": true,
            "idChat": "3",
            "roomName": "Iba RP",
            "lastLogin": 1333308615
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 9,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbums": 0,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": "Som narcis a co Aj jedno slovo potop\u00ed sny...Aj jeden de\u0148\r\nzmen\u00ed \u017eivot...Aj jeden poh\u013ead dok\u00e1\u017ee\r\nu\u010darova\u0165...Aj jedno objatie dok\u00e1\u017ee naplni\u0165\r\npr\u00e1zdnu du\u0161u...",
            "addTime": "1332089086"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false,
        "noAddGift": 1
    };aBubbleData[
        'majinka155'
    ]={
        "idUser": 4433815,
        "nick": "Majinka155",
        "photo": 1,
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 7,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "sefNick": "majinka155",
        "profilPercent": 100,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 22,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/n_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1",
            "medium": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/m_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1",
            "24x24": "PARAM_pm.aimg.sk\/profil\/s_4433815PARAM_ext?v=1"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "0000-00-00"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "6",
            "regionName": "Tren\u010diansky kraj",
            "idCity": "137",
            "cityName": "Nem\u0161ov\u00e1"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": true,
            "isChating": true,
            "idChat": "9",
            "roomName": "Do pohody",
            "lastLogin": 1333306831
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 7,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbums": 0,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": "\u017eivot ti rany d\u00e1va, ale ty nie si sama, m\u00e1\u0161 skvel\u00fa l\u00e1sku a nie len na obr\u00e1zku, m\u00e1\u0161 milovan\u00fa os\u00f4bku, \u010do pri tebe stoj\u00ed, preto sa v\u0161etko na svete zahoj\u00ed...",
            "addTime": "1332102387"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false,
        "noAddGift": 1
    }
```

Maybe I can use REGEX and extract all nicks and profiles to LIST and then create json string which I can deserialize.

Or do you have better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is quite simple, so I think you could use regex here. A record starts with a `aBubbleData` literal, then a set of square brackets with a nickname in quotes inside it, an equals sign. Then goes profile data which ends with a semicolon with either a `aBubbleData` literal, or end of the string anchor.

Here is a simple regex for this (I used named groups for `nick` and `profile`):

```
var regex = new Regex(
    @"aBubbleData\[\s*'(?<nick>\w+)'\s*\]=(?<profile>.*?);(?=aBubbleData|$)", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline
);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    var nick = match.Groups["nick"].Value;
    var profile = match.Groups["profile"].Value;
    // you could deserialize profile here
}
```

But if your data structure become complicated I think you should consider writing your data parser.